What’s a word for deliberately slow and sexy?
I’ve been trying to spice up my word choice this and surprise myself. Right now I’m having writer’s block; I need a good word that describes doing something slow and sexy. Words like languid come to mind, but I’d like any other words that might fit.
If I were to use the word in a sentence, I would say something along the lines of:

Then, straddling him, she found the hem of her shirt with her hands and _____ pulled it up and over her head.

Or maybe something like:

Getting up, she stretched _____ in front of him, never failing to make his heart skip a beat when she had the chance.


I don't like guessing games, but you could try seductive(ly), vampy, suggestive, or elegant in your thesaurus (or preferably multiple thesauri).

There's an entire subplot to the 1987 movie "Throw Momma From The Train" that revolves around a writer having writer's block, not being unable to figure out a good  evocative word for something both hot and humid. The discovery of the right word precipitates the climax

I'm feeling teasingly, but this is a guessing game. The right word here is the one you want to remember rather than the word to be used next time someone looks up this answer.

That’s true. I think it might have been languidly, but it might just be me looking for any sort of answer. I’ll edit the question to generalise it and make it more helpful to anyone who stumbles upon it in the future.

If single-word requests belong in StackExchange, wouldn't this one be better placed in SE Writing, for instance?

I can only speculate about the word you once knew.
Possibilities probably include:

sultry
carnal
voluptuous
sensuous

and, (thanks to @Graffito) also:

lascivious(ly)
languorous(ly)

apart from the obvious

erotic
amorous
sensual

I don't know which dictionary you used, but mine had all those mentioned above (and a few less fitting, like "animal"). You might consider replacing your dictionary.

The OP already discarded sensuous/sensual. You might also want to check which words you listed would fit in the sample sentence, and explain why they are appropriate for "slow and sexy".  I see the "sexy" but not the "slow"

"lascivious(ly)" or "languorous(ly)" may be added to the list.

Hello, these are good words that I do use in my writing. However, I am looking for words similar to the definition of languid; that is, slow and provocative, often in a sensual manner. If I find it or it returns to me, I will come back to update the thread.

@Graffito languoursly is the only word that is slow AND sexy.

@Mari-LouA: this is why I listed it under "apart from the obvious" as a candidate I did not include in the list of suggestions.

I'd add a dictionary definition for 'sultry/sultrily' that includes 'suggestive/ly':  surely precluding 'lively/in a lively fashion'?

Consider slinkily:

in a sexually attractive way, or in a slow way that suggests sex:

A slinkily dressed woman met us at the door and showed us the way.
She reclined slinkily across the piano and lowered her voice to a whisper.

Cambridge Dictionary


Seek and you shall find :)

Languid or languidly is the most fitting if it is to include the idea of slowness.
Oxford Learners Dictionaries:

​moving slowly in an attractive way, not needing energy or effort


You need to add some authority to demonstrate that your answer is so. If you don't do this, it will be removed.
